# Website footer has no style on server but does locally

Tags: css, linux, server

My server is linux based.

My footer and the headers within the cards have style when viewed locally, but when hosted on the server they go to default. I have contacted systems administrator and they have no idea either.
**Local**
[image: Local]

**Online**
[image: Online]

Comment: look at F12 and see what happend to your style(if it override by other)(show me link to website)

Comment: website is www.bysteveroe.com

Comment: This is gonna be a stupid question but I'm just a beginner, I'm on Mac. Does F12 still apply?

Comment: when I show in `network` tab the `all.css` I can not see any style to `page_footer` are you set the right file??(BTW your picture is amazing)

Comment: Thank you very much! So I've been doing my style through SASS, and I've just checked to see if it has been writing to CSS properly. But still the styles seem to be working locally?

Comment: can you show me any example in fiddle... (with sass)! But my suggest try to upload the **right** file again

Comment: I think I need to recalibrate the sass file to the css file and it should be working fine. I'm not very familiar with fiddle I'm not sure how to work it.

Comment: here :https://jsfiddle.net/8vLfyxuc/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8vLfyxuc/ not sure if I did that right

Comment: Ah wait, I've got it working on Safari and Firefox but not on Chrome now. I recalibrated the SASS file

Comment: How to fix on Chrome?

Comment: All fixed, thanks for your help dude!